# Training multiple models using multiprocessing

Tags: python, machine-learning, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to use multiprocessing to train multiple models with different algorithms at the same time. For example, a Naive bayes model and a RandomForest model being trained parallel to each other on the same dataset. I am using concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() to accomplish this but I'm running into an error.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score , f1_score , recall_score, precision_score
import time
import concurrent.futures 

df = pd.read_csv(".\DATA\heart.csv")

X = df.iloc[:,:-1] # We get all but the output column
y = pd.DataFrame(df["output"]) # We get output column

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.15 , random_state = 53)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = scaler.transform(x_test)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    from sklearn.svm import SVC
    from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

    start = time.perf_counter()

    # list of algorithms names
    algo_name = [BernoulliNB, RandomForestClassifier, SVC, SGDClassifier]

    # function to train the model and print the accuracy 
    def train(algo_name) : 
        model = algo_name().fit(x_train, y_train)
        y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
        acc = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
        f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred)
        prec = precision_score(y_test, y_pred)
        recall = recall_score(y_test, y_pred)
        print("--------------------------------")
        print("Accuracy: ", round(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)*100, 2), "%")
        print("F1 accuracy: ", round(f1_score(y_test, y_pred)*100, 2), "%")
        print("Precision: ", round(precision_score(y_test, y_pred)*100, 2), "%")
        print("Recall : ", round(recall_score(y_test, y_pred)*100, 2), "%")
        print("--------------------------------")

    # run the train function with every item in the algo_name list parallel to each other
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor: 
        executor.map(train, algo_name)

    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Program runtime is {round((end - start) * 1000 , 2)} ms')
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Process SpawnProcess-2:
Process SpawnProcess-4:
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Process SpawnProcess-3:
```

Worth mentioning that when I change concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() to concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() the program runs just fine but there is no time improvement than from running the program sequentially.

Comment: No idea why you're getting a blank error message, but the code between the imports and the `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard should probably also be inside the guard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote this slightly as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```py
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import time
import concurrent.futures
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=10_000)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    start = time.perf_counter()

    algo_name = [BernoulliNB, RandomForestClassifier, SVC, SGDClassifier]

    def train(algo_name) :
        model = algo_name().fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
        print(model, accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(train, algo_name)

    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Program runtime is {round((end - start) * 1000 , 2)} ms')
```

And got the output:

```
BernoulliNB() 0.9196
SGDClassifier() 0.94
SVC() 0.9652
RandomForestClassifier() 0.9736
Program runtime is 1978.72 ms
```

Running Python `3.10.6` with `scikit-learn==1.2.0` on an Ubuntu machine.

scikit-learn has separate ways of dealing with parallelism (e.g. see the documentation on [Parallelism, resource management, and configuration](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/computing/parallelism.html)) which *might* be interfering.

---

System details from `sklearn.show_versions()` in case it is useful:

```
System:
    python: 3.10.6 (main, Oct 24 2022, 16:07:47) [GCC 11.2.0]
executable: /home/hayesall/miniconda3/envs/srlearn/bin/python
   machine: Linux-5.15.0-56-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35

Python dependencies:
      sklearn: 1.2.0
          pip: 22.2.2
   setuptools: 65.5.0
        numpy: 1.23.4
        scipy: 1.9.3
       Cython: None
       pandas: 1.5.2
   matplotlib: 3.6.2
       joblib: 1.2.0
threadpoolctl: 3.1.0

Built with OpenMP: True

threadpoolctl info:
       user_api: openmp
   internal_api: openmp
         prefix: libgomp
       filepath: /home/hayesall/miniconda3/envs/srlearn/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scikit_learn.libs/libgomp-a34b3233.so.1.0.0
        version: None
    num_threads: 8

       user_api: blas
   internal_api: openblas
         prefix: libopenblas
       filepath: /home/hayesall/miniconda3/envs/srlearn/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy.libs/libopenblas64_p-r0-742d56dc.3.20.so
        version: 0.3.20
threading_layer: pthreads
   architecture: Haswell
    num_threads: 8

       user_api: blas
   internal_api: openblas
         prefix: libopenblas
       filepath: /home/hayesall/miniconda3/envs/srlearn/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scipy.libs/libopenblasp-r0-41284840.3.18.so
        version: 0.3.18
threading_layer: pthreads
   architecture: Haswell
    num_threads: 8
```